# How to create a document with unequal page sizes in iText 7

Tags: java, itext, itext7

How to create a document with unequal page sizes in iText 7?

Is it possible in iText7?

In iText5, I used `document.setPageSize()` and `document.newPage()`.

Comment: Yes. several approaches exist by changing page size at `Document` level. The best approach to take will depend on your usecase. If you need a new page after certain content is added, you can set the page-size and add a page-break element to force a new page, if you need something like a landscape page every X pages, page events are your best bet, etc.

Comment: Yes, I want to add a new page(different page-kind) after certain content is added. How to set the page-size and add a page-break element to force a new page? I need a help. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're adding content through the high-level API (`Document.add()` and its ilk), and the desired page-size is directly tied to specific content, modifying the default page-size through `PdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize` is probably the cleanest and easiest way to go about it, like this:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
    pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A5);//All pages will be added using this page size
    String paragraphOneText = "I have seen the face of sorrow\n" +
            "She looks away in the distance\n" +
            "Across all these bridges\n" +
            "From whence I came\n" +
            "And those spans, trussed and arched\n" +
            "Hold up our lives as we go back again\n" +
            "To how we thought then\n" +
            "To how we thought we thought then";
    String paragraphTwoText = "I have seen sorrow's face,\n" +
            "But she is ever turned away\n" +
            "And her words leave me blind\n" +
            "Her eyes make me mute\n" +
            "I do not understand what she says to me\n" +
            "I do not know if to obey\n" +
            "Or attempt a flood of tears";
    String paragraphThreeText  = "I have seen her face\n" +
            "She does not speak\n" +
            "She does not weep\n" +
            "She does not know me\n" +
            "For I am but a stone fitted in place\n" +
            "On the bridge where she walks";
    String attribution = "--Toc the Younger";

    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(paragraphOneText);
    //Current default pagesize is A5, so any new pages will be created as A5
    doc.add(p);
    //Changing default pagesize will affect any new pages that are created
    pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A5.rotate());
    //Adding an areabreak of type NEXT_PAGE will force the creation of a new page
    doc.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
    p = new Paragraph(paragraphTwoText);
    doc.add(p);
    pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A5);
    doc.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
    p = new Paragraph(paragraphThreeText);
    doc.add(p);
    p= new Paragraph(attribution);
    doc.add(p);
    doc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it might work

```
Rectangle one = new Rectangle(70,140);
document.setPageSize(one);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Document class in iText7 doesn't have setPageSize() api.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
PageSize PageSize = new PageSize(100,50);

PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(memoryStream));
pdfDoc.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize);
```