# Different PageSize for each page in itext 7

Tags: itext7

I need the page size to change to a certain page.

For example if page 3 i set pageSize A4.

If page 2 i set pageSize new Rectangle(155,155)

```
 String line = "Hello! Welcome to iTextPdf";
    Div div = new Div();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            Paragraph element = new Paragraph();
            element.add(line + " " + i);
      

            paragraphs.add(element);

        }



--------------
  if(page==1) // This is just for an example. How I want it to be
   pdf.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A5);
   else if(page==3)
 element.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);
```

Comment: Hi, have you seen this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46707630/how-to-create-a-document-with-unequal-page-sizes-in-itext-7)? If yes and the accepted answer does not help, can you elaborate on what is different about your use case?

Comment: @ Alexey Subach I don't know how many pages there will be at the beginning, I add a lot of data from the array. I have a large text and I add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `DocumentRenderer` class and customize `#addNewPage`:

```
private static class CustomDocumentRenderer extends DocumentRenderer {
    public CustomDocumentRenderer(Document document) {
        super(document);
    }

    @Override
    protected PageSize addNewPage(PageSize customPageSize) {
        if (customPageSize != null) {
            document.getPdfDocument().addNewPage(customPageSize);
            return customPageSize;
        } else {
            PageSize pageSize = definePageSizeBasedOnPageNumber(document.getPdfDocument().getNumberOfPages() + 1);
            document.getPdfDocument().addNewPage(pageSize);
            return pageSize;
        }
    }

    private PageSize definePageSizeBasedOnPageNumber(int curPageNumber) {
        if (curPageNumber % 2 == 1) {
            return PageSize.A4;
        } else {
            return PageSize.A4.rotate();
        }
    }
}
```

Here we have a helper private method `definePageSizeBasedOnPageNumber` to define the page size based on the page number.

Using this customized renderer is very simple now: `document.setRenderer(new CustomDocumentRenderer(document));`

Full snippet of code at the highest execution level:

```
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
document.setRenderer(new CustomDocumentRenderer(document));

String line = "Hello! Welcome to iTextPdf";
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    Paragraph element = new Paragraph();
    element.add(line + " " + i);
    document.add(element);
}

document.close();
```